# Lighted ankle straps

Tags: safety, lighting, visibility

I read an [article in the Wall Street Journal](https://www.wsj.com/articles/how-cyclists-can-stay-safe-on-the-road-1498906860) about a recent study that concluded that [motion-based lighting is the most effective technique](https://www.roadbikerider.com/latest-rbr-newsletter-2017/288-issue-no-770/2978-incisive-new-studies-on-cyclist-visibility) for drawing motorists' attention.  I believe the recommended that cyclists wear a lighted strap around their ankles so their leg movement will be visible from any angle.

Do any products exist yet like this?

Comment: Cars are required to have lights almost everywhere, and you'll need quite powerful light to beat a reflector reflecting even low beams. But of course you can find the product if you bother to search at all.

Comment: I have seen similar things on runners.  But simply having reflectors on the pedals (plus reflective clothing) is probably just as effective.

Comment: I have a reflective band with about 6 LED's I use for night riding. Runs off a CR2032 button Cell. e.g. https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Roadway-Safety-Flashing-LED-Armband-Running_60231019435.html

Comment: @mattnz something like that is exactly what I'd been hoping to find--just found it on ebay for ~$2 shipped from Hong Kong. I'd seen the ones in Criggie's answer as long as 15 years ago; the ones I've seen are quite dim, and not going to as useful as direct light from multiple bright LEDS.

Comment: @ojs that assumes (i) the presence of a car with lights on (problems: bike paths; dusk, when not everyone has turned their lights on), and (ii) that the car's lights are pointing at you (not always true at junctions, e.g. as you approach a car waiting to join the road you're on).

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Since that's a short answer, here's some examples (without making any sort of recommendation)

http://www.dx.com/p/outdoor-sports-blue-light-3-mode-led-flashing-safety-armband-black-2-cr2032-425777#.WaxcC3Wg9hE

http://www.dx.com/p/outdoor-cycling-reflective-safety-3-mode-led-nylon-armband-w-buckle-green-2-x-cr2032-339927#.WaxcA3Wg9hE

[image]

Do consider the colour before wearing - In my country Blue (police) and Green (medical service private transport) are reserved colours that must not feature on a road vehicle.  Also Red must not face forward and White must not face rear (unless reversing)

I have used something similar to the blue one and it works as described, but they're not bright enough to see with.  2x CR2016 batteries don't last long, and CR2032 are only marginally better.

You could also get the same effect using electroluminescent wire and stitching it to a velcro strap.

The easiest solution is to use a small red rear light and clip it to the back of your traffic-side foot or pedal.  Some risk of it falling off though.

Comment: That picture is a bit fancier than the one I used to have (found on a bike path) but they've been around for years, usually sold as armbands. Here in the UK, the lighting rules are much less strict for lights storm on the person than for lights attached to the bike; I by know whether this applies in other countries. I'm not saying that red facing forwards is a good idea even attached to your leg but you could get away with it

Comment: Bright yellow + reflectorised overshoes or clipless riding shoes have the same effect, more-so in daylight.  One chap locally can be seen miles away because his feet are so encased, and doing the up/down pump means they're highly noticeable.